# What is the difference between cts:count, cts:frequency, fn:count in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

What is the difference between `cts:count`, `cts:frequency`, `fn:count` in MarkLogic?

Could you please support me with example?

Answer (score 7):

## [**`cts:count`**](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:count)

is deprecated and it was designed to take a sequence of values returned by a lexicon function (for example, `cts:element-values`); if you input non-lexicon values, the result will always be 0.

**You should use** `cts:count-aggregate` **instead.**

The `cts:count-aggregate` function works like `cts:count` except it performs the counting in parallel in all data nodes then aggregates the values. It generally performs better than `cts:count`, especially on large clusters

See: https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:count-aggregate

## [**`cts:frequency`**](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:frequency)

Returns an integer representing the number of times in which a particular value occurs in a value lexicon lookup (for example, `cts:element-values`). When using the fragment-frequency lexicon option, `cts:frequency` returns the number of fragments in which the lexicon value occurs. When using the item-frequency lexicon option, `cts:frequency` returns the total number of times in which the lexicon value occurs in each item.

See https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:frequency

## [**`fn:count`**](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:count)

Returns the number of items in a sequence

See https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:count

See the different links for samples

Comment: Thanks Prker, Actually I already read the documentation before submitting this question But I didn't got the point, also their example is not clear at all. at least if they put the file content of the example.  by the way thanks again, I would like to ask u if u can support me with a different and more clear example.

Comment: Note also the benefits of speed if you use `xdmp:estimate` at http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:estimate.  If it's possible to use `xdmp:estimate`, my understanding is that the speed is much faster.  I also understand from the article that `xdmp:estimate` can be mostly accurate, but because it uses JUST indexes to search, it may not be fully accurate.  If a rough estimate is acceptable, sounds good to me.

Comment: xdmp:estimate is faster because it draws only on the indexes. It's accuracy depends on how well the configured indexes support what you're trying to estimate. fn:count loops through a list to count it; it can be slow, especially if it needs to pull docs from disk. [Good read to compare the two.](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/count_estimate)